# Folder icon splits into two on desktop

Tags: macos, mojave, folders, icon, desktop

When I change desktops using trackpad swipe, the games folder on my desktop freaks out and glitches, I don't know how it happened and it has just started today. My MacBook is running Mojave.

See the top row in the photo:

[image: [1]]

Comment: hi! What do you mean by "change window" ?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii When I swipe between desktops using the trackpad gestures